# Finding the distribution for the sample mean from a normal distribution not knowing its size

Tags: self-study, sample-size, mean

My Intro to statistics professor asked this question in class today:

If the mean of a normal distribution is 1 and the standard deviation is 2, what is the probability of a negative sample mean?

My professor insists that the question is complete and correct. So while can I find the probability using the sample means formula when the sample size $n$ is unknown?

Comment: Has your Prof. given any hint. I don't think you can do this with CLT without sample size. My best guess would be to use the empirical rule.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183678/find-probability-of-sample-mean-if-sample-size-is-unknown/

Same question

Comment: On a normal distribution, there is NO need of the sample size.

Comment: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/sampling_distributions/samp_dist_mean.html if you look at this source, I think you'll find you are mistaken.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it seems that the question simply is "give me the answer that my professor wants to see". I had tried to point into a possible direction of solving the problem and figured it was at least a valid approach making explicit assumptions. Getting downvoted for that kind of participation without being told *why* top me not only does not offer any learning-experience but - worse - degenerates to a waste of my precious time. To bad.